# How do proxy servers change their IPs?

Tags: proxy, ip, ip-address

A lot of proxy servers say that they change their outgoing IP addresses every X hours (many seem to do it twice daily). How they do this?

Is it something that a hosting company would do, or an ISP?

Comment: The key to both of those answers is that the proxy server will have access to a pool of IP addresses and rotate between them every *x* hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be done on the router either by regularly changing the outbound gateway IP address on the routing table or by utilizing an outbound IP address pool. Some routers allow selecting an outgoing IP from a pool of addresses based on user, user class, per session, per connection, or just randomly. If the IP address changes on a schedule it is most likely a script changing the outbound gateway address.

This can also be accomplished in the browser itself if you have multiple gateways by using a [Proxy Auto Config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) file.

Answer (score 3):

I don't work for one of these companies. But my best guess is that they are behind a natting device that rotates the outbound nat via a script every X hours.